# Storage increased sharply when download from google play

Tags: android, storage

My issue is : my app have capacity 20MB and when I install to my phone it use 20MB storage . But when I upload to google play and download it and setup it use 60MB storage . This only happens with my Paid app . If you have any suggestions please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Care to give any sort of context or more information? Other than "my app is 40MB bigger than I expected", that doesn't give us much info.

Answer (score 0):

To help you at the very least with the limited information you provided, check out [this guide](http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/tutorials/android_tutorial/tips-for-reducing-apk-file-size-2/) to reducing the size of droid apps.